# Return records from table where date column is between a second tables date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have question using sql which i cannot get my head around.

I have a primary table (clockins) with 2 columns (in_time, out_time) and the below records.

```
2017-01-17 06:00:00.000 to  2017-01-17 07:00:00.000
2017-01-17 09:00:00.000 to  2017-01-17 11:00:00.000
2017-01-17 17:00:00.000 to  2017-01-17 20:00:00.000
```

I then have second lookup table (shifts) that also has 2 datetime columns.
(shiftstart,shiftend)

```
2015-01-17 06:00:00.000 to 2015-01-17 16:00:00.000
2015-01-17 18:00:00.000 to 2015-01-17 23:00:00.000
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to show the total difference in minutes from my primary table (clockins) where the in_time is between the dates in the second table.

I have tried a sub query using the "between", but the shifts table has more than 1 record i have to check against. Another solution i tried was using a loop on the shifts table and then just using a select query based on each record from the shifts table. This works but i can see this becoming very slow.

Based on the above information, the 1st and 2nd row frm the clockins table should be returned with a result of 3 hours = 180 min and omit record 2017-01-17 17:00:00.000

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There's no need for including tags in titles. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles for some additional information.

Comment: Is there a common field between two tables, something like `shiftId` ?

Comment: Yes sorry it was a typo - its all 2015. Im using MS SQL server 2008. I will look at your post and provide feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but the following is standard SQL (assuming out_time and in_time are really `timestamp` columns). It will produce an `interval` as the result:

```
select c.out_time - c.in_time as duration
from clockins c
  join shifts s on c.in_time between s.shiftstart and s.shiftend;
```

The above assumes that the year 2017 is a typo in your sample data. If you indeed have different years in the timestamp and you *only* want to compare the time of the clockins you would need to do something like this (again: this is standard SQL)

```
select c.out_time - c.in_time as duration
from clockins c
  join shifts s on cast(c.in_time as time) between cast(s.shiftstart as time) and cast(s.shiftend as time);
```

This will ignore the date part of the timestamps completely

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/75a47/1

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to determine if datetime ranges overlap.
If you don't have a common field between the two tables try this:

```
select Sum(DATEDIFF(hh, a.in_time, a.out_time)) as hoursWorkedThisShift
from clockins a
WHERE a.in_time <= '2015-01-17 16:00:00.000' and a.out_time >= '2015-01-17 06:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Im not sure if that work. If the comparison values were indeed 1 record, then it would fine. The values I need to compare are in the second table and could be 5 records or so.

Comment: i need something like this - select datediff(minute,in_time,out_tme)[my result]  from dbo.clockins c
where in_time >= (select ShiftStart from dbo.shifts)
and  in_time <= (select ShiftEnd from dbo.shifts)